# wordpress remove uploaded file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a simple script to upload file in my WordPress plugin using

```
wp_handle_upload
```

In database only link to this image is stored. I would like to delete this uploaded file when i delete the post which it is linked to, however using

```
unlink()
```

does not work due to link structure which looks like this:
http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/image.jpg

Does Anyone know the way to remove "http://[ip]/" from path or any **WordPress method to remove uploaded file**

I would be grateful for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [get_home_path()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path) to get the root directory. Then your code would be:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/image.jpg';
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH); // Remove "http://localhost"
$fullPath = get_home_path() . $path;
unlink($fullPath);
```

Comment: But how to remove http://[ip]/ from 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/image.jpg' to get 'wp-content/uploads/2016/10/image.jpg' ?

Comment: You can use `parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)` for this. See updated answer.